# Java Inheritance: empty method in parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I was wondering if it is frowned upon to have an empty function in a parent class for child classes to override if they needed it? I personally think the use case below justifies it -

```
class Foo {

    void performAdditionalChecksIfNeeded(String decrypted) {
    }

    void validate(String encrypted) {
        final String decrypted = decryptIfProperlyEncrypted(encrypted);
        performAdditionalChecksIfNeeded(decrypted);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    @override
    void performAdditionalChecksIfNeeded(String decrypted) {
        // Additional validation logic
    }
}
```

I'm aware that `Bar` class could've simply overridden `validate()` and called `super.validate()` to eliminate the need of the empty function in `Foo`. The reason why I had the code arranged this way is that `decryptIfProperlyEncrypted` uses a library that I wanted to keep only in the `Foo` class due to separation of concern, performance concerns (decryption), and code duplication avoidance. In other words, if `performAdditionalChecksIfNeeded` didn't exist in `Foo` I'd have to perform the decryption again in `Bar`.

Comment: I don't see why it should be a problem. There are more functional alternatives, but an empty overridable method is a reasonable approach to some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use composition over inheritance in this case? The only thing Foo class seems to be doing is the decryption. I would use it in Bar class as a dependency.

Comment: The decryption method throws an exception if the encrypted string made no sense, in some of our use cases that is the only validation needed (to see if something is properly encrypted)

Comment: I don't see it as a validation, it is a decryption operation that can go wrong if the data isn't valid. This operation could be encapsulated inside a class and used where it is necessary.